# how to use Django redirect to the original request after login

Tags: python, django

I practice how to use django login , but it can't redirect to the page before login
Please teach me how to do it  Thank you very much

My project name is :proj
And I have an app name: app1

when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/f/index/` it will redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/f/index/`

and after I enter the username and password,
I want to redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/f/index/` ( by the parameter  `?next=/f/index/`)  but don't know how to do .

app1/views.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
def index(request):
       logger.info('test')
       ....
```

proj/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'proj.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'proj.views.logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'proj.views.auth_view'),
```

proj/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import  csrf

def login(request):
    c={}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('proj/login.html',c)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    password = request.POST.get('password','')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next')) #not work
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')
```

proj/login.html:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <p class="error">Sorry.that's not valid  </p>
{% endif %}


<form action="/accounts/auth/?next={{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="username" >User name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
    <label for="password" >Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. check [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in). Do you want to redirect user to `login` page or don’t. Are you getting any error?

Comment: when you are accessing the `index` view what is happening? or after success login redirect to what page ?

Comment: sorry,I edit my question to describe the detail. When I try ````return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next'))```` there is error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' and requesturl is````http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/auth/?next=```` seems it can't get the ````next```` parameter

Answer (score 0):

try this in `views.py`:

```
if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/f/index/')
```

Answer (score 0):

when you type url, and you are not login before, and django redirect to the url :`http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/f/index/`
after entering your username and password, and click submit button, django redirect you automatically to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/f/index/`
using URLresolver.